# how to update parent object field with child object's field?

Tags: formula, workflow

I have 2 objects: `Account` as the parent object and `Account Team Member` as the child object. I want to update a field (`Customer_Lead`) on `Account` object with the `Name` field of `Account Team Member` object, of that team member who has the checkbox field on `Account Team Member` object checked.
By taking `Customer_Lead` as formula I'm not able to access the child object field.
By creating a workflow rule on `Account Team Member`'s checkbox field, the previous records will not get updated.

Is there some other way possible to do this??

Answer (score 7):

You should Work With `Cross object Formula` Field Which is used to update the master object's Field when Child Object,s Field is Changed.
You Can Get More info from the Following link.
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_cross_object_field_updates.htm&language=en_US